# Get the first body tag in a document with multiple bodies

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a html document containing an inline SVG with some `<foreignObject>`s in it. Those all have an own `<body>` tag.

Now I want to find the top `<body>`.

A simple solution would be

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
```

but this seems to be inefficient (because it would first select all bodies and then drop all but the first) and I'm not quite sure if it's really reliable (is the ordering in such a set actually defined or may this change with other/newer browsers?)

Can see someone another way which is both efficient and reliable?

Comment: "this seems to be inefficient" — [Have you benchmarked it? Is it really inefficient?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization)

Comment: document.body perhaps?

Comment: So select the first element and than select the body of that element.

Comment: @Quentin No, I haven't benchmarked it. It's just an assumption.

Comment: @epascarello — "select the first element": How? "select the body of that element": How? Given the question is about performance, would that two step process really be faster?

Comment: @BoltClock Yes sure, this would do in my case. A shame I didn't think of that myself. Thanks!

Comment: WRT the ordering, DOM selection methods maintain a consistent document order of a depth-first traversal.

Comment: @Quentin OP thinks that selecting X number of elements is slower so I am answering their question with one where that do not... I am not saying that it is better or more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML document doesn't actually have multiple bodies as you allude to in the title, despite what the presence of `body` elements within the `foreignObject` elements might suggest.

Your HTML document still has only one body, its own `body` element, of which the `foreignObject` elements are descendants. This is *always* represented by `document.body`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, `getElementsByTagName`:

> Returns a NodeList of all the Elements with a given tag name in the order in which they would be encountered in a preorder traversal of the Document tree.

So, *"is the ordering in such a set actually defined?"*. Yes, it returns the elements in the order they appear in the tree structure.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.body` element which returns the `<body>` element.
if you need the `<html>` element then the `documenut.documentElement` can be used